# How to create a Scala presentation compiler inside Ammonite REPL?

Tags: scala, classpath, read-eval-print-loop, scala-compiler, ammonite

I want to create a Scala presentation compiler in Ammonite REPL, however I always got the error of `Missing dependency 'object scala in compiler mirror'`.

I have tried the workaround mentioned in [object scala in compiler mirror not found - running Scala compiler programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934282/object-scala-in-compiler-mirror-not-found-running-scala-compiler-programatical) . Unfortunately it does not work.

How to make it work?

```
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 1.0.0
(Scala 2.12.2 Java 1.8.0_131)
If you like Ammonite, please support our development at www.patreon.com/lihaoyi
@ import scala.tools.nsc.Settings 
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
@ import scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global 
import scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global
@ import scala.tools.nsc.reporters.ConsoleReporter 
import scala.tools.nsc.reporters.ConsoleReporter
@ val settings = new Settings() 
settings: Settings = Settings {
  -d = .
}

@ settings.usejavacp.value = true 

@ val reporter = new ConsoleReporter(settings) 
reporter: ConsoleReporter = scala.tools.nsc.reporters.ConsoleReporter@4a24170b
@ val compiler = new Global(settings, reporter) 
error: error while loading Object, Missing dependency 'object scala in compiler mirror', required by /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class)
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala in compiler mirror not found.
  scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
  scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
  scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.$anonfun$getModuleOrClass$4(Mirrors.scala:54)
  scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:54)
  scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
  scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getPackage(Mirrors.scala:172)
  scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ScalaPackage$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:169)
  scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ScalaPackage(Definitions.scala:169)
  scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ScalaPackageClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:170)
  scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ScalaPackageClass(Definitions.scala:170)
  scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1447)
  scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1149)
  scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global$TyperRun.<init>(Global.scala:1308)
  scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global.newTyperRun(Global.scala:1331)
  scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global.<init>(Global.scala:286)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd6$.<init>(cmd6.sc:1)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd6$.<clinit>(cmd6.sc)
```

The same code works in official Scala REPL.

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings

scala> import scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global
import scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global

scala> import scala.tools.nsc.reporters.ConsoleReporter
import scala.tools.nsc.reporters.ConsoleReporter

scala> val settings = new Settings()
settings: scala.tools.nsc.Settings =
Settings {
  -d = .
}

scala> settings.usejavacp.value = true
settings.usejavacp.value: Boolean = true

scala> val reporter = new ConsoleReporter(settings)
reporter: scala.tools.nsc.reporters.ConsoleReporter = scala.tools.nsc.reporters.ConsoleReporter@7eeb38b2

scala> val compiler = new Global(settings, reporter)
compiler: scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global = scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global@3b6a4b91
```

Comment: I get the same error when trying out Lihaoyi's mill project in a windows/cygwin environment.   I'm not sure what the common denominator might be, since it looks like you're working on a Mac.